# Codeigniter calling different API's - where to put the API calls

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I am making a system where a users account can pull in details about their Facebook, Twitter and a few other API's.

I have been doing it so it brings in the data into the Controller, but is this the right thing to do? I know that "Codeigniter is great because you can use it any way you want it just depends on how you feel comfortable" etc etc but I find I am repeating myself sometimes if I have to bring in latest Tweets in more than one controller, for example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To use an API you have to download API required files in libraries folder and then load library into the controller.
You are then good to go to make API calls.

Here is a sample tutorial: 
http://codezone4.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/codeigniter-facebook-login-tutorial-using-facebook-php-sdk/

Comment: Noooo I know how to use them. I have made my own MY_Controller and extended all my other CI controllers to include the files at the top. That way I can have a common function to instantiate the API Auth and have all controllers access it. It's just I seem to be repeating code between controllers for simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create libraries for each, then initialize library to the controllers where you want to use the data.

This is how you [create library in CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).